# Get index of value in a nested list

Tags: c#, list

I'm having a bit of trouble with nested lists in C#.

```
List<List<string>> nestedList = new List<List<string>>();
nestedList.Add(new List<string> { "test1" } );
nestedList.Add(new List<string> { "test2" } );
nestedList.Add(new List<string> { "test3" } );
```

So if I'm correct the nestedList now has 3 different lists in it, each with one value.

What I'm trying to do is

```
if (nestedList[0[0]]) == "test1")
```

(If the first value of the first list equals `"test1"`)

What can I do to find out if a specific index of the list contains `"test1"`?

Comment: Here's a hint: `List<string> firstNestedList = nestedList[0];` - What do you do to access the first item of a list?

Comment: you should not access like `nestedList[0[0]]`. you should do like this `nestedList[0][0]`

Answer (score 1):

Your guess was almost correct. What you want to use is `nestedList[0][0]`:

```
List<List<string>> nestedList = new List<List<string>>();
nestedList.Add(new List<string> { "test1" } );
nestedList.Add(new List<string> { "test2" } );
nestedList.Add(new List<string> { "test3" } );

if (nestedList[0][0] == "test1")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Test 1!");
}
```

If it helps you understand the syntax, here's an equivalent piece of code:

```
List<List<string>> nestedList = new List<List<string>>();
nestedList.Add(new List<string> { "test1" } );
nestedList.Add(new List<string> { "test2" } );
nestedList.Add(new List<string> { "test3" } );

List<string> firstList = nestedList[0]; // Here's your new List<string> { "test1" }
if (firstList[0] == "test1")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Test 1!");
}
```

However, **you want to be careful** when accessing sub-lists like so if you're not absolutely certain that all of the lists have been populated. For example, the following example will greet you with an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` because there's no items inside the `List<string>` returned by `nestedList[0]`:

```
List<List<string>> nestedList = new List<List<string>>();
nestedList.Add(new List<string>());
nestedList.Add(new List<string>());
nestedList.Add(new List<string>());

if (nestedList[0][0] == "test1") // Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.Parameter name: index
{
    Console.WriteLine("Test 1!");
}
```

You can make sure by, for example, first checking the parent list item count:

```
if (nestedList[0].Count> 0 && nestedList[0][0] == "test1")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Test 1!");
}
```

If you want a safe way to access the first element of anything implementing the `IEnumerable<T>` interface (basically *every* collection class in the framework), you can use the LINQ (add `using System.Linq;`) [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
if (nestedList[0].FirstOrDefault() == "test1")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Test 1!");
}
```

When the elements of the enumerable are `class`es, the method returns either the first element of the enumerable or `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
nestedList[0][0]
```

The second [0] accesses an index of the nested list. Since `list[0]` gives the first element of the list, list[0][0] gives the first element of the first element of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to query the nested list to get the item and if you get it, use the [`IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get the index

```
List<List<string>> nestedList = new List<List<string>>();
nestedList.Add(new List<string> { "test1" } );
nestedList.Add(new List<string> { "test2" } );
nestedList.Add(new List<string> { "test3" } );

var tocheck="test3";

var item = nestedList.Where(s=>s.Any(d=>d==tocheck)).FirstOrDefault();
if(item!=null)
{
   var itemIndex=nestedList.IndexOf(item);
  // Console.WriteLine(itemIndex);
}
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OXEoT6) is a working dotnet fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need to access that specific index, then your way would be:

```
nestedList[0][0]; //("test1")
nestedList[1][0]; //("test2") ...
```

But if you need to find which index contains that string you should use some method like this:

```
  public int Test(string value)
    {
        List<List<string>> nestedList = new List<List<string>>();
        nestedList.Add(new List<string> { "test1" });
        nestedList.Add(new List<string> { "test2" });
        nestedList.Add(new List<string> { "test3" });

        for (int i = 0; i < nestedList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (nestedList[i].Any(m => m == value))
                return i;
        }

        //not found
        return -1;
    }

    //To use:
    public void Program() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("found in index: {0}", Test("test3")); //found in index: 2 
        Console.WriteLine("found in index: {0}", Test("test4")); //found in index: -1
    }
```